# ng-grid and real-time data memory leak

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, socket.io, ng-grid

I am trying to use ng-grid to visualize high-frequency real-time data, but I am having problems with a memory leak. The memory leak is not present when I use a simple html table with ng-repeat.

I am using node+express on the backend and angularjs on client side.
I use socket.io to stream real-time data from the server to a table on the client side.

I have reproduced the memory problem in a simplified example:

I send 1500 messages per sec, each message is an object like this one
{id: 1, name: “name”, time: “[current date/time string]”}
after 4 minutes the browser memory is above 400MiB and after 10 minutes is above 1GiB

I have tested on Chrome and Firefox.

Here is the simplified example, am I doing something wrong? (Additional information added at the end).

**server**

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.of('/test').on('connection',  function (socket) {

    console.log('socket connection: /test');

    for (id=1; id<16; id++) {
        streamData(id);
    }

    function streamData(id) {
      setInterval(function () {
        socket.emit('updateData', {
            id: id, 
            name: "test"+id, 
            time: (new Date()).toString()
        });
      }, 10);
    }
});
```

**service** using [angular-socket-io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io)

```
factory('testSocket', function(socketFactory) {
    return socketFactory({
        ioSocket:  io.connect('http://localhost/test')
    });
})
```

**controller**

```
controller('NgGridTestCtrl', function ($scope, testSocket) {     
  var itemsObj = {};
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.gridOptions = { 
      data: 'items',
      columnDefs: [{field:'id', displayName:'ID', width:'15%'}, 
                   {field:'name', displayName:'Name', width:'20%'},
                   {field:'time', displayName:'Date and Time', width:'65%'}],
      enableColumnResize: true    
  };

  testSocket.on('updateData', function(data) {
      itemsObj[data.id] = data;
      var values = [];
      angular.forEach(itemsObj, function(value, index) {
          this.push(value);
      }, values);

      // the data for ng-grid
      $scope.items = values;
  });

});
```

**ngGrid template**

```
<div>
   <h1>ng-grid table</h1>
   <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>   
</div>
```

---

**Edited to add plain table example**

using a plain table gives no memory issue, the browser memory stays at about 155MiB

**controller**

```
  controller('SimpleTableCtrl', function ($scope, testSocket) {
     $scope.items = {};
      testSocket.on('updateData', function(data) {
          $scope.items[data.id] = data;
      });      
  }).
```

**plain table template**

```
<div>
  <h1>Simple table with ng-repeat</h1>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.time}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Additional observations**

1. The memory problem is not just related to ng-grid; it manifests itself also using the "NgGridTestCtrl" controller with the "plain table template" with ng-repeat.
2. The memory problem doesn't manifest itself (with ng-grid template and NgGridTestCtrl) if the frequency of the data is lower, (500 milliseconds instead of 10 milliseconds interval in the streamData function).
3. The memory problem is still prestent, (with plain table template and NgGridCtrl), if the frequency of the data is lower, (500 milliseconds instead of 10 milliseconds interval in the streamData function). The memory just grows at a slower rate, as one might expect.
4. **The higher frequency data don't result in memory problems when the "SimpleTableCtrl" with "plain table template" are used.**
5. I have not yet been able to use ng-grid with the higher frequency data. Anybody knows if ng-grid can actually perform with high frequency data?

Comment: hey did you ever resolve this? how is it performing?

Comment: @parliament no, I am using a plain table for now, with which I have no memory problems. Do you have the same issue with ng-grid?

Comment: I'm building a signalR test harness for it right now, will let you know. However, I'm not sure I can say your example is a memory leak, as you are loading 1500 messages/sec into memory. Why wouldn't it increase?

Comment: I did however note that printing gridOptions shows that ng-grid stores the data in memory 3 times. Curiously posted an issue bout it here https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1021. So that would actually be 4500 msg/sec being loaded into memory in your example

Comment: @parliament the issue with ng-grid is that the memory keeps growing, never reaching a saturation value. For comparison, I display the same data with a plain table, and this has no memory issues, the memory sets to a value about 150MiB.

Comment: @parliament debugging this test with a fresh mind, I just realized that the problem is related to what I do in the testSocket.on('updateData') callback function, when I convert the data from object to array. If I use that same pattern in the controller of the plain table example, I also get memory issue.

Comment: @parliament, I was wondering how did your test go? Did you menage to get good performance using ng-grid with high frequency data?

Comment: the issue got deferred with some other development so I didnt have a chance yet sorry. They just released a new version of ng-grid a few days ago def check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think at first you need to find where is your memory leak. For this you can use "Heap Allocation" at Chrome:

F12 -> Profiles -> Record Heap Allocation.

Here the topic:

[Object allocation tracking](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/revolutions2013/)